# Project DataTable into new structure with Linq

Tags: linq

I have a DataTable I would like massage into a new format (here is what it comes out like when attached to a gridview):

```
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                Line
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                StartTime
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                EndTime
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Attribute
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Value
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line1
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:30:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Actual
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line1
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:30:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                ProductCategory
            </td>
            <td>
                FFAC
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line1
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:30:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Target
            </td>
            <td>
                36.5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line2
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:26:50 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Actual
            </td>
            <td>
                69
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line2
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:26:50 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                ProductCategory
            </td>
            <td>
                FFAC
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line2
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:26:50 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Target
            </td>
            <td>
                55.5555582046509
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line3
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:20 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:47:50 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Actual
            </td>
            <td>
                1475
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line3
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:20 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:47:50 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                ProductCategory
            </td>
            <td>
                FFAC
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line3
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:20 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:47:50 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Target
            </td>
            <td>
                202.430557310581
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line4
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:31:30 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Actual
            </td>
            <td>
                1384
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line4
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:31:30 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                ProductCategory
            </td>
            <td>
                FFAC
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line4
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:31:30 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Target
            </td>
            <td>
                3179.26381587982
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line5
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:37:00 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Actual
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line5
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:37:00 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                ProductCategory
            </td>
            <td>
                FHHT
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Line5
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:37:00 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Target
            </td>
            <td>
                92.6652171770756
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                P2_Bundler
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 7:35:00 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                24/01/2013 8:00:10 AM
            </td>
            <td>
                Actual
            </td>
            <td>
                7
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I know that if the records have the same line, start and end times, the records are related.

What I want to do is get a sum of the Actual and Target values grouped by the ProductCategory. In other words:

```
ProductCategory | Sum(Actual) | Sum(Target)

FFAC            | 1000        | 2000

FHHT            | 200         | 175
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

You won't have any massage here ;)

The structure of your dataTable would be more usefull than the grid code, but to get what you want from your DataTable, you should do something like that.

```
var result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(m => m.Field<string>("ProductCategory"))
              .Select(g => new {
                  productCategory = g.Key,
                  sumActual = g.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Actual")),
                  sumTarget = g.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Target"))
               });
```

Comment: Wow, you're fast :) I am getting an error under g.Key: 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

Comment: @ChrisHardie could you show the structure of your DataTable ?

Comment: @ChrisHardie :  a few `)` were missing. Corrected. But still not sure of your DataTable structure.

Comment: Hi Raphael, I'm unsure how to better demonstrate the structure of the DataTable than by the <table> markup in the original question. The columns are "Line", "StartTime", "EndTime", "Attribute", and "Value". When I run your LINQ query, I get "Column 'ProductCategory' does not belong to table." 'ProductCategory' is actually the value of the "Attribute" column in some records, not a column itself, which is why I'm having difficulty grouping by it.

Comment: @ChrisHardie but you talk about DataTable, which is a c# class... Does that DataTable exist ? To be clear, what's the origin of the data in your GridView ?

Comment: Yes, the DataTable exists. I bound it to a gridview for the purpose of showing its structure, so it is indeed the origin of the data.

Comment: @ChrisHardie so what I'm asking for is the code where your create (and populate maybe) that DataTable...

Comment: The code is pretty typical, I fill the data table via an adapter. The SQL used to generate it is: SELECT ef.Name AS Line, ef.StartTime, ef.EndTime, efa.Name AS Attribute,cast(efs.Value as String) as Value 
                FROM [Reporting].[EventFrame].[EventFrame] ef
                INNER JOIN [Reporting].[EventFrame].[EventFrameAttribute] efa ON efa.EventFrameID = ef.ID 
                INNER JOIN [Reporting].[Data].[EventFrameSnapshot] efs ON efs.EventFrameAttributeID = efa.ID
                WHERE (efa.Name =N'ProductCategory' or efa.Name =N'Actual' or efa.Name=N'Target')

Answer (score 0):

Oi, I thought this was going to be more difficult than anticipated, but it ended up being easier and I rewrote this. You perform your grouping on the line, but then you just have to query the rows in each group to get the ProductCategory.

First, you're going to group by the main key, which in this case I believe is the `Line` column. So:

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(m => m.Field<string>("Line"))
```

Next, we're going to have to find the category for each of these groupings. Since each grouping is an `IEnumerable<T>`, just perform a `Select` after filtering our `Attribute` as `ProductCategory` and get the first value. I use a little "defensive" coding by accounting for the situation where no `ProductCategory` attribute exists:

```
    ...
    .Select(g => new 
        { 
            ProductCategory = g.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Attribute") == "ProductCategory")
                        .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Value"))
                        .FirstOrDefault() ?? "No Category",
            SumActual = g.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Actual")),
            SumTarget = g.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Target"))
        })
```

Edit: Alright, so now I see what you're saying. My original thoughts were correct in that you're grouping each original group (based on Line) into further groups. There really isn't an easy way, and the options aren't pretty. It's the fact that you have to group each group, but in order to group the group, you have to query the group for a single entity, then aggregate based on another 2 entities (making it very difficult to use LINQ here).

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(m => m.Field<string>("Line"))
    .Select(g => new
        {
            ProductCategory = g.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Attribute") == "ProductCategory")
                        .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Value"))
                        .FirstOrDefault() ?? "No Category",
            Actual = g.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Attribute") == "Actual")
                        .Select(r => 
                            { 
                                decimal d = 0m; 
                                Decimal.TryParse(r.Field<string>("Value"), out d);
                                return d;
                            }
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
            Target = g.Where(r => r.Field<string>("Attribute") == "Target")
                        .Select(r => 
                            { 
                                decimal d = 0m; 
                                Decimal.TryParse(r.Field<string>("Value"), out d);
                                return d;
                            }
                        .FirstOrDefault()
        })
    .GroupBy(n => n.ProductCategory)
    .Select(g => new
        {
            ProductCategory = g.Key,
            SumActual = g.Sum(x => x.Actual),
            SumTarget = g.Sum(x => x.Target)
        })
```

Again, not very pretty... Especially since your "Value" column is string, you have to parse them in order to get a meaningful value (in this case, summing a number). The premise here is that you group all your records into "blocks", then compose these blocks into single anonymous objects. So each anonymous object represents all datarow Attribute/Value pairs for a particular Line. From there, you just group based on your desired key (ProductCategory in this case), and perform your required aggregates.

PS, I would actually perform this query on the DB side using a PIVOT. Might take a bit more setup, but then you give the system designed to perform this type of data crunching/aggregation the work that it can handle, and keep your front-end CPU cycles for something more important.

Comment: The issue is "ProductCategory" isn't a field of the DataTable. Only "Line", "StartTime", "EndTime", "Attribute", and "Value" are valid fields. "ProductCategory" is a possible value for the Attribute field. The complexity here is I'm not looking to group by a column, but I need to surface certain field values in such a way that I can group by those. I think I may need to create a placeholder collection I can shove values into and then query off that.

Comment: My bad, that was supposed to group by "Line", not "ProductCategory". That's what I wrote in the description above, but I guess my copy/pasta job failed me.

Comment: Ah, I see. But "Actual" and "Target" aren't columns in the original data table either, they are also possible values for the "Attribute" column :)

Comment: Ahh, I gotcha. Alright, give me a moment to wrap my head around this.